# How does height of a div relate to font size

Tags: html, css

Assume I have no additional CSS rules(only browser default css)

I created a div like this:

```
<div style="font-size:40px;">a</div>
```

I try to measure the height of the div in chrome and firefox. 
I used offsetHeight attribute on the div node.

In chrome, I get 46px.
In firefox it is 48px.

I am really curious how the offsetHeight of div is related to the fontsize of text within
Is there browser spec for these ratios?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the `line-height` property for the element the text is in. In most browsers the default is 1.2, or 1.2 times the font size used in the element. Hence why it is 48px.

You can set the `line-height` property yourself for an element if you want it to be a specific size, either a unitless number that will be a ratio of the font-size, or an explicit px value.